# How to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.10?

Tags: 11.10, 12.10, upgrade

I want to update the Ubuntu on my laptop to 12.10 from the current version 11.10, when I click on the update manager I get a partial update GUI, if I click cancel on that I get the GUI for update which has three buttons check, install updates and upgrade. The upgrade button upgrades only to 12.04.1.LTS, when I press check it checks and gives me this error:

```
"W:Failed to fetch h t t p://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/lb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch h t t p://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/lb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/lb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_i18n_Index
, W:Failed to fetch http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/lb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Index
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/lb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Index
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/lb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_restrivted_i18n_Index

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/lb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Index

sudo apt-get update
```

This will remove the cached apt lists. And update them again, to get the newest.